# PayPal Here SDK w/ Xamarin and c#

Tags: c#, paypal, xamarin.android

I work for a company that has c150 retail stores here in the UK.  We are trying to implement PayPal Here in our stores, so we have a PayPal Here card reader on trial.

We write our own software in C# so it is thought the best way forward would be a Xamarin app to live on an Android tablet.  The solution is being developed in Visual Studio 2017.

After browsing PayPal.com and following this link https://github.com/paypal/paypal-here-sdk-android-distribution/tree/master/sdk.  We downloaded the AAR files and placed them in to a Android Bindings Library project.

The AAR is located in the "Jars" directory and the Build Action is set to "LibraryProjectZip".

There is only 1 of the AAR files used at any time, but all 4 will not build.

They all produce some 60 errors which include types like :-

"...Already contains a definition for..."
"...does not implement inherited abstract member..."
"Inconsistent accessibility..."

It doesn't seem to make a difference which Android version is targeted and versions of the AAR going back to 1.6.5 have been tried with the same results.

Has anyone come across this or even managed to get a working Xamarin product?

Comment: I find the documents for you https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings/ ,https://gist.github.com/JonDouglas/dda6d8ace7d071b0e8cb ,both of them are talking about the problem when we use AAR file in Xamarin.Androd.

Comment: Thanks Joe Lv, I'll take a look at this...keeping my fingers crossed my answer is in there somewhere!!

Answer (score 0):

https://www.paypal-business.com/SDKdeveloperinterestregistration - Complete your details here and a PayPal Sales engineer will be assigned to help you with this.

Comment: Hi Rebecca and thanks, I had found this page and put my details in.  I have, quite literally, got a reply today from PayPal wanting to arrange a call about this but not sure if this is with a tech person or not.

In the meantime, I decided to start looking at how to implement the libraries in Java instead...which seems to be a doddle in IntelliJ IDEA...so I think I'll be doing the project from within there.